# Using autocomplete in input controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an issue in using of autocomplete when using "SuggestAppend" mode. When I finishes with edit text in certain (say) combobox, program navigates to next control. But if I return back to those combobox, my text, which I input inside for autosuggesting + appending stays remembered from last time what is not good in my program scenario.

Instead of that native behavior I would like that combobox, when I leave it, "forget" what I typed and resets that (searched) string to "nothing" like it is when program starts.

I believe this is internal procedure but I also believe that some hack may exist to achieve that functionality which may improve my program logic.

Comment: You could try to clear the Text property when the control receives or loses Focus.

Comment: Of course, I tried that and many other things but without result. Searched keystrokes remains memorized somewhere inside.